# Refresh news periodically in background (android)

Tags: android, background

I've created an app which will fetch news from the internet and cache it in a Room db. However, I would like the app to do this periodically e.g. 7AM every day, in the background so that when the app is opened, it will display the latest news without needing to manually refresh and wait.

I was wondering what the best way to do this was? I've read up about WorkManager and it seems like the newest api which will call between FirebaseJobDispatcher, GcmNetworkManager, and Job Scheduler based on the API level for us. Is WorkManager the best approach for my use case? I would require approximately 5 queries via Retrofit.

Comment: Waiting for a better answer because upon trying out the only answer it is incorrect. It is not for cases where you update at a specific time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, WorkManager is the best solution for above use case.

As per official documentation: `WorkManager is intended for work that is deferrable—that is, not required to run immediately—and required to run reliably even if the app exits or the device restarts.`

And you can set One Time OR Periodic Work Request based on your use case.
Also, you can add constraints to your work for better control.